# Property 'initializeApp' does not exist on type 'typeof import(/././projectfolder/node_modules/firebase'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework

This question is actually similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884563/angular-how-to-fix-property-does-not-exist-on-type-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097820/property-does-not-exist-on-type-object-observable-subscribe)

I am setting up the config.ts file for Firebase. 'initializeApp' is not working and giving the error in the title above. Just wondering if this is a firebase global install issue or if I should be calling initializeApp differently.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { config } from 'process'

const config = {

}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this??

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to check if I could import * as firebase from 'firebase' from different paths, local or global,     but it seems like doing the regular import solved it, ugh. The standard import firebase from 'firebase' worked, but it made firebase.initializeApp make it (alias) namespace. So i was suspicious'

Comment: Oh cool I recently found one of your react ionic articles

Comment: there is alot of ionic react content on my youtube channel and dev.to

Comment: Hi Aaron is it okay to use .JS files in Ionic instead of .TSX files? I find I've fixed some issues by doing this.

Comment: @JedLancer yes you can